# Running Python Scripts from Anywhere

Tags: python, powershell, path

I'm new to programming. Giving this another try.

I've been able to make Python run from PowerShell through changing the Environment variables. When I try to launch Python using Win + R, only py launches python. This puzzles me. PowerShell and cmd have no problem with just typing `python`.

I'm also trying to make it so that I can launch a python script from anywhere. I made a simple script called again.py in visual studio code and saved the script in a specific folder. When I try to run the script in VSC, I always get the error:

`[Running] python -u "c:\Users\xyz\Programming\Python\again.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

`[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.137 seconds`

By my understanding, if a folder is included in Path, and a file is called that is stored within that folder, the file/script should run. I should be able to call that file from anywhere, but I am just not able to type the file name in PowerShell or Run and have it run.

win + R returns:

`Windows cannot find 'again.py'. Make sure you type the name correctly, and try again.`

PowerShell: start again.py

`start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start again.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand`

Typing again.py into cmd causes it to run just fine.

Comment: Can you run `python` in VSC? What is your actual PATH?

Comment: For the **User Variable for xyz**, the **Variable Name** is `PYTHON_HOME` **Variable Value** is `C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` I also added `;C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` to **Path** in **System Variables**.

Comment: Somehow trying to launch Python using the terminal is VSC fails. 
This is what I get: And `PS C:\Users\xyz> Start Python`

`start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start python etc` Shouldn't VSC just be able to find Python? How do I tell VSC where to look for Python?

Comment: lol. When using `start again.py` this actually launches the code in VSC. The shebang doesn't even matter. Man it's such a simple program. I'm puzzled as to why it won't run. 

`#! python

msg = "Hello World"
print = ("Hello World")`

Answer (score 0):

The Powershell error is caused by a space in the file name. Powershell looks at input, `start again.py`, and parses it like so

```
first token on row is word "start"
    start is an alias to start-process
second token on row is "again.py"
    that will be passed as argument to start-process
```

The easiest work-around is to avoid spaces in file names. Use an underscore or camel case instead. That is, `startAgain.py` or `start_again.py`. One *can* use spaces, but there are extra quoting tricks involved. What's worse, those depend on shell. Cmd has its own rules, Powershell has very different ones. Since you are learning how to program, consider focusing on Python for now and worry later on shell quoting issues.

Comment: For some reason just typing the name of a program into PowerShell sometimes returns errors. So usually I have to use either `Start` on this laptop or `Start-Process` on my desktop. Since I'm using this laptop to learn, an example of that usage is `Start Chrome` to launch Google Chrome and so to start my simple script this should work `Start again.py`.